# Executing CScript scripts from an ASP script fails

Tags: windows-server-2003, scripting, iis

Context: Windows Server 2003; IIS 5

I'm trying to launch a JScript file from within an IIS application. I keep getting

```
Permission denied 70 0 Microsoft VBScript runtime error
```

Just in case you're thinking that it's because I'm having a JScript/VBScript senior moment, I'm using the VBScript tool in a third party CGI to execute the JScript, using the following bit of VBScript:

```
 ans = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe //B ..\js2\script3.js group-name 1004041814
```

So the error appears to be happening either in the call to cscript or in cscript itself reporting back that it can't do what it's been told.

I've done a lot of digging around for an answer, but so far none of the suggestions given have worked. If nothing else, I'd just like to know what's going on, even if a fix isn't possible. I have come up with a couple of workaround since, but it's a drag that the thing doesn't work in the first instance.

Answer (score 1):

The IUSR account, or whatever account your IIS application is running under, doesn't have NTFS permissions to cscript.exe, script3.js, some resource that the script3.js is trying to access or a combination of the aforementioned.

I would start by seeing if you're able to launch a blank version of script3.js using the same process. If that doesn't throw the error, then start checking permissions on resources that your script is trying to access or write to.